# Can I use this CSV to load a neo4j graph with cypher?

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I am a medical doctor trying to model a drugs to enzymes database and am starting with a CSV file I use to load my data into the Gephi graph layouting program. I understand the power of a graph db but am illiterate with cypher:

The current CSV has the following format:

```
source;target;arc_type; <- this is an header needed for Gephi import
artemisinin;2B6;induces;
...
amiodarone;1A2;represses;
...
3A457;carbamazepine;metabolizes;
```

These sample records show the three types of relationships. Drugs can repress or augment a cytochrome, and cytochromes metabolize drugs.

Is there a way to use this CSV as is to load into neo4j and create the graph?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do nodes also have a type  ?

Comment: Yes the graph is a bipartite graph with two types of nodes: cytochromes and xenobiotics (this term comprises both drugs and other bioactive substances such as tobacco). There are only edges between a cytochrome and a xenobiotic.

Answer (score 1):

In neo4j terminology, a [relationship](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-relationships) must have "type", and a node can have any number of [labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels). It looks like your use case could benefit from labelling your nodes with either `Drug` or `Cytochrome`.

Here is a possible neo4j data model for your use case:

```
(:Drug)-[:MODULATES {induces: false}]->(:Cytochrome)
(:Cytochrome)-[:METABOLIZES]->(:Drug)
```

The `induces` property has a boolean value indicating whether a drug induces (true) or represses (false) the related cythochrome.

The following is a (somewhat complex) query that generates the above data model from your CSV file:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Drugs.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
WITH line,
  CASE line.arc_type
    WHEN 'metabolizes' THEN {a: [1]}
    WHEN 'induces' THEN {b: [true]}
    ELSE {b: [false]}
  END AS todo
FOREACH (ignored IN todo.a |
  MERGE (c:Cytochrome {id: line.source})
  MERGE (d:Drug {id: line.target})
  MERGE (c)-[:METABOLIZES]->(d)
)
FOREACH (induces IN todo.b |
  MERGE (d:Drug {id: line.source})
  MERGE (c:Cytochrome {id: line.target})
  MERGE (d)-[:MODULATES {induces: induces}]->(c)
)
```

The [FOREACH](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/foreach/) clause does nothing if the value after the `IN` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, but you will need to install APOC : a list of usefull stored procedures for Neo4j. You can find it here : https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/

Then you should put your CSV file into the `import` folder of Neo4j, and run those queries :

The first one to create a unique constraint on `:Node(name)` :

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE;
```

And then this query to import your data :

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///my-csv-file.csv' AS line
  MERGE (n:Node {name:line.source})
  MERGE (m:Node {name:line.target})
  CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, line.arc_type,{​}, m)
```

Comment: Tried the following starting from your example:

{USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Users/Bob/dcn_graph_data.csv' AS line WITH
  MERGE (n:Node {name:line.source})
  MERGE (m:Node {name:line.target})
  CALL apoc.create.relationship(n, line.arc_type,{}, m)
}
but get the following error

Invalid input ')': expected whitespace or a relationship pattern (line 3, column 35 (offset: 139))
"  MERGE (n:Node {name:line.source})"

Comment: @RobertAlexander You can't do `WITH MERGE`, WITH is its own clause, you need at least one variable here, or get rid of the WITH entirely

Comment: as written without the WITH clause it throws an error. The other example worked well though. thank you so much.